# Gitlab General project settings option pages

Tags: gitlab

I don't understand why, in my general GitLab Project, i don't have pages option

[see here the screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTXyh.png).

Have you and idea please ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is this on gitlab.com? Or is this on some private gitlab installation?

Comment: This is a private gitlab installation but in an other project, i have this page option, it's  incredible !

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the [Giltab Pages Administation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/pages/#configuration) instructions?

Specifically did you set this in your `gitlab.rb` config file:

```
pages_external_url 'http://example.io'
```

Comment: It's interesting, i 'll check this. But if i have this page for one project, normaly, it's ok for all projects...

Comment: I just see one thing. For  all projects, i have option pages but for subgroups 's projects, this option is not visible...